# Adobe AIR - Options to open folder in Windows Explorer

Tags: apache-flex, file, air, windows-explorer

Hello StackOverflow community,

Is there any way to open a folder in Windows Explorer from Adobe AIR?

It looks like these APIs won't be added until AIR 2.0, but until then are there any workarounds that can be used to enable this feature?

Thanks,
Mauricio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to launch a new URLRequest for the file name.  In theory, it will send that request to the default browser on the Windows machine, which will probably open the folder.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public function clickButton():void{
var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest('C:\\projects\\');
navigateToURL(request )    
}
]]></mx:Script>

<mx:Button click="clickButton()" />
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Code sample taken from one of my older blog posts:
http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2008/4/22/Using-AIR-to-launch-other-applications

Comment: Until AIR 2.0 release I believe this is the only approach we can use. Thanks!

Comment: It does open the browser window, but the folder contents are directly displayed inside the browser. The Windows explorer dialog is not launched. How can we open the Window Explorer dialog?